# Overriding Bootstrap doesn't take immediate effect

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap

This has been bothering me, my custom CSS doesn't always take immediate effect. For example I was experimenting moving my `form` and `submit` button around trying to get them to align and all was working fine until put my laptop to sleep. I came back and it wouldn't update immediately anymore. Then I had to leave my house so I put it back to sleep and when I came back and refreshed my website (localhost) the changes were applied. Here's my template code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-override.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>



  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>  
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form method="POST" class= "post-form navbar-form"> {% csrf_token%}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type='submit' class="save btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>



<div class="container">
    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="col-md-12">


        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>Personal Training</h3>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>Physiotherapy</h3>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-console" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>Boxing</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div> 
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my custom CSS file:

```
    .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 500px; 
}

.save-btn-default {
    position: relative;left:425px;top:-47px;
}

.post-form {
    position: relative;right:275px;top:-30px;
}
```

Was causes this?

Comment: Why you are adding `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` 2 times? And make sure that your custom stylesheet should be the last one in order.

Comment: I think I was following two tutorials and I ended up putting both in. I just edited the code to exclude `jquery.min.js` and placed my custom CSS below the default theme. Seems to have worked for now

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Okay so the problem seems to have appeared again. Is it something with the server? Is there some feature preventing it from updating immediately every time? I edited my code to show you what I changed it to. When I inspect the element it just shows that the specifications I gave it haven't changed.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) here you added bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js two times.
>
> 2) better to write your custom css before closing the head tag.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have done the trick. So should I put my custom stylesheet after the `jquery.min.js` line? I put it before it and it's working